# How to catch overwriting of libumem's redzone?

Tags: c++, solaris, memory-corruption, libumem

Is it possible to catch overwriting of libumem's redzone? 
I uses libumem to analyze a memory corruption and found that redzone of some block is the following:

```
...
feedface        edfecefa
8014822         18a0a5ea
...
```

and all blocks after this are swapped the same way. Need to find out where/how it could occur.

Comment: Look in the sourcecode. Other than that, you can create memory-based breakpoints in some debuggers that will trigger when certain memory ranges are accessed.

Comment: Have you looked at using [watchmalloc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36874/watchmalloc-3malloc.html) or the Solaris Studio [bcheck](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37069_01/html/E37078/blaio.html#scrolltoc) utility?